# Attaching onPress handler to a Text that was constructed outside the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have my component class, let's call it `MyComponent`. It has a complicated execution logic, but here's how it looks like with unnecessary code snippets omitted:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    justWarn(input) {
        console.warn(input);
        // do something with `this` as well
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {this.props.myText}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    // Call the getText function here
    return {
        myText: getText()
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Now the function `getText` is defined in some other file, and looks like this:

```
function getText() {
    // Let's assume it returns hard-coded value for the sake of brevity

    return (
        <Text>
            <Text>I am the first part</Text>
            <Text
            onPress={function(){
                // I want to call the function that is defined inside MyComponent
                // since this Text will eventually be a part of MyComponent
                this.justWarn('Warn me in the yellow box')
            }}
            >I am the clickable part
            </Text>
        </Text>
    );
}
```

When I try to call the `justWarn` method defined inside the `MyComponent` from the `Text` as defined above, I get an error `undefined is not a function, evaluating this.justWarn`.

My question is, I am not using the arrow function, and as such `this` is not bound on when I declare the `onPress` handler. It is actually called when `Text` is a part of `MyComponent`, so shouldn't `this` correspond to `MyComponent` and code above should work fine?

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any way to achieve this by keeping the `getText` and `MyComponent` split in two files?

Thanks.

Comment: try to pass that function from component using props

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `getText` does not have `this` context so you need to bind it in someway that it gets the context.

One way to achieve this is by changing `MyComponent` like this-

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    justWarn(input) {
        console.warn(input);
        alert(input)
        // do something with `this` as well
    }

    render() {
        const myText = this.props.myText.bind(this)
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>something should render</Text>
                {myText()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
    // Call the getText function here
    return {
        myText: getText
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

...

and then using arrow function in onPress event handler like this -

```
function getText() {
    // Let's assume it returns hard-coded value for the sake of brevity

    return (
        <Text>
            <Text>I am the first part</Text>
            <Text
              onPress={() => {this.justWarn('Warn me in the yellow box')}}
            >I am the clickable part
            </Text>
        </Text>
    );
}
```

...

Hope it helps.